# Allowing drag and drop in UICollectionView (moveItemAtIndexPath) just for specific cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm currently working in a project where I need to have a drag and drop functionality in a CollectionView. I added moveItemAtIndexPath so I could have drag and drop reordering of the cells. It looks something like this:

[image]

I need to disable this functionality for some of the cells, while allowing the others to move. For example cell 1 and 3 will always stay in the same places but the other ones can be rearranged. Is this posible?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a tutorial on how to do the dragging [enter link description here](http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-rearrange-uicollectionviews-through-layouts/) and for That just working on the ones you want, and forbidding moving the ones you don't, just create an if to skip the method of the tutorial when the collection items is number 1 or 3.

Comment: Will try it out and mark it as an answer if it works. Thanks!